# Error in fetching data through WAMP Server on Local Hosting using phpMyAdmin while matching the password column for matching

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am trying to fetch a data , insert and check wether the user Id and Password match on a  php script and implementing MySQL database on phpMy admin

The Code is given Below

```
<?php

require "start.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$db=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

if(isset($_POST['Email'],$_POST['Password']))
{
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$password=$_POST['Password'];

if(!empty($email)&&!empty($password))
{
    check_if_exist($email,$password,$db);

}
else
{
    echo json_encode("You Must fill both the Fields");
}
}

function check_if_exist($email,$password,$db)
{
    $query="Select * from loginsignup where Email='$email' and    Password='$password';";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    $json['success']='Welcome'.$email;
    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($db);
}
else{
    $query="Insert into loginsignup values('$email','$password');";
    $isinserted=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if($isinserted)
    {
        $json['success']='Welcome New User'.$email;
    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($db);
    }else
    {
        $json['error']='Wrong Password';
        echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($db);
    }
}
}


?>
```

The Error that I am getting while running this post on Postman is when I am trying to send the same data through post. In stead of doing a login on the same Password ans Showing success it fails to check for correct password and shows as if the passowords dont match.
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07neX.png)

I Think there is something wrong with this part of the Program

```
$query="Select * from loginsignup where Email='$email' and    Password='$password';";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    $json['success']='Welcome'.$email;
    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

But Cant seem to understand what.

Comment: 1) Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections 2) Use [mysqli_error](http://www.php.net/mysqli_error) before `mysql_num_rows` and print the outcome. Your screenshot suggests your query fails.

Comment: I am not worried about injection as of yet . This is my first go at php and hence I am focusing on basic functionality.  2) I already tried printing MySQLi.error(); . it is empty. Not displaying anything

Comment: And yes the query is failing . I even tried a basic query * Select all from loginsignup ;* Even that is failing and I don't understand why. All this while the insertion works fine.

Comment: From this code what you want to do is not clear. I tried your code it is working fine. I found no error. And also there is  no condition to print `$json['error']='Wrong Password';` In your code you check the user exist or not. If exist print the email otherwise insert the email and password. And you are not encoding password field. Use and password encoding method for that. And check your php server version also. Please clear what you want?

Comment: In my code , I first check if the user exists or not by marching both email and password.  Now if the email and password completely matches , then user exists.  Now if it does not , there can be 2 cases . 1) User exist but he entered wrong password 2) User does not exist and wishes to register . So I try to insert the email and password in my database. Since my email is primary key , it will be unique and it  won't allow redundant entry. If the user does not exist , the command will enter it into database using insert into command and if insert fails (I.e email present ) , it will show error